# Why shouldn't I use Lemon Dawn to wash a cat?

Tags: cats, health, fleas

There is an answer [on Biology.SE, indicating that lemon dawn can help control fleas but also should not be used on cats.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17370/can-dish-soap-really-be-used-to-kill-ticks-and-fleas/37134#37134) What "adverse reactions" do Limonene and Linalool have on cats?  How is this different from reactions on other species?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a case study](http://avmajournals.avma.org/doi/abs/10.2460/javma.2002.221.258) to show that limonene can definitely be toxic, but I can't find any information on concentration/dosages (work seems to be pre-epubs), nor info on how much limonene/linalool are in lemon dawn.

Based on this information, I would avoid it just based on an abundance of caution, not because it's likely to be harmful.